# What is the purpose of getVersion() in GWT's RequestFactory?

Tags: hibernate, gwt, gxt, requestfactory

GWT's `RequestFactory` requires that I implement a `getVersion()` method in all my entity objects. I just have them all returning `0` and marked as `@Transient` and everything works fine.

Why do I need it? It's annoying as hell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taken from: http://code.google.com/intl/pl/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideRequestFactory.html

> Used by RequestFactory to infer if an entity has changed. The backing
>   store (JDO, JPA, etc.) is responsible for updating the version each
>   time the object is persisted, and RequestFactory calls getVersion() to
>   learn of changes. This information is used in two places. First, the
>   RequestFactoryServlet sends an UPDATE event to the client if an entity
>   changes as a result of the method invocation on the server, for
>   example, when a call to persist an editable entity results in an
>   updated version on the server. Second, the client maintains a version
>   cache of recently seen entities. Whenever it sees an entity whose
>   version has changed, it fires UPDATE events on the event bus so that
>   listeners can update the view.

So your method should return versioning value diffrent each time when it changes. If you don't need Request Factory entity transport system consider to use ValueProxy instead of EntityProxy.

Comment: Just a note that the "client-side cache" actually doesn't exist (it was only in pre-2.1 milestones); IIRC the server will send an UPDATE for each proxy that it returns and that isn't DELETED (which has almost the same result on the client-side).

Comment: You must be aware Travis that GWT (especially Request Factory) is very dynamic project and so I encourage you to follow not only documentation cause it maight be outdated, but also discussion group and solved issues.